# According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions

Tags: java, jstl

I have a project where I need to display details of movies in an HTML page. I must strictly follow MVC although I am not using any framework like Spring or Struts. I am also not allowed to use scriptlets, but use JSTL and expression language. I usually retrieve data from database and then set it to a bean and then make a list of those bean and pass it to JSP and then print those details. But how would I achieve it if I am not allowed to use JSP. If I use servlet to retrieve those data and set it to a bean and then to a list and pass it through request dispatcher, how am I going to get each bean from the list in the HTML page?

I could not get this JSTL working. I am using Netbeans 7.0 and Apache Tomcat 7.

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>DVD Guru</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>   
     <div id="wrapper">     
        <c:set var="testing" value="blah"/>
                <c:out value="${testing}"/>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I get following error

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions

I have imported JSTL 1.1 library from project properties.
Should anything else should be done?

Comment: Do you mean plain HTML instead of JSP?

Comment: yes using html page...but its not possible only using plain html i must use jstl as i need to iterate through the list and then get individual bean...

Comment: You need to use JSP, HTML is not a server-side component like (JSP).

Comment: okay thnks i must use .jsp to let the server know that it must compile it first.Thnks for the suggestion.

Comment: The error which you got is originated by `<c:forEach items>`, but this is not visible in the code provided so far. Please provide the *real* code and don't overgeneralize code.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You must use **JSP**, *JSTL* - is just set of custom tags and can not be used separately. As well as *Expression Language*. If you are not using any MVC frameworks, then you need to do some of their work by yourself. Please take a look (if you haven't yet) at following design patterns:

1. `Front Controller`, `Command` for simple application
2. `Front Controller`, `View Helper` for more complex application

**UPD**:

To resolve issue with EL, please try to correct JSTL uri in your JSP to:

```
 <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
```

Answer (score 29):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Your JSTL taglib URI is wrong. The one which you've there is for legacy JSTL 1.0. Since JSTL 1.1 there's an additional `/jsp` path in the taglib URI, because expression language (those `${}` things) has been moved from JSTL to JSP and hence taglibs of JSTL 1.0 and 1.1 are not interchangeable.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Nothing more needs to be done, assuming that Netbeans is smart enough to autogenerate a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` for Tomcat 7.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: thanks, also fixed an issue I was having.  shame there's no way for the IDE to tell you off. :)

Answer (score 11):

Change your JSTL taglib uri to the following:

```jsp
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
```

It works like a charm.

Comment: I faced the same problem, By changing uri i got the solution. Thanks..

Comment: In jstl-1.2.jar you have tp use folowing tag. The one which you are using is for legacy JSTL 1.0. 
use this:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

nstead of 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Answer (score 2):

You can generate HTML even by concatenating of strings. Or you may use any of text template engines like simple JMTE(Java Minimal Template Engine) or more advanced like Velocity or StringTemplate. Using another template engine you could bravely state that you don't use JSP. Although I don't see much difference between JSP and other template engines, I mean this your requirement is kind of stupid.

Even better: don't use JSP use JSF 2! )

Answer (score 1):

Try using the prefix

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>`

instead of

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when trying to use variable in the jstl XML, I want to use the `randInt` in `<x:out select/>`:

`<x:out select="$parsedXML/content/${randInt}/title"/>`

Solved it by using `pageContext`

```
<%
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randInt = rand.nextInt();
    pageContext.setAttribute("randInt", randInt);
%>
<x:out select="$parsedXML/content/article[$pageScope:randInt]/title"/>
```