# jstl: access session variable

Tags: jsp, session, jstl

In the servlet, I set session value

```
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
session.setAttribute("user", "adam");
```

Then, on the JSP page, when I try to get the value `<c:out value="${user}"></c:out>`, I got the error `According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions`

Then how can I get the session variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889431/access-session-attribute-on-jstl

Comment: @MichałRybak I used the answer provided by this link, and it doesn't work

Comment: sorry, I was misguided by the title... 
what does your taglib import look like?

Comment: according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428788/according-to-tld-or-attribute-directive-in-tag-file-attribute-items-does-not-ac)  your issue can maybe be resolved by correcting taglib declaration, but without looking into your code I can't say anything ;)

Comment: @MichałRybak Then I got this error `The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` even though I used `jstl-1.2.jar`

Comment: @MichałRybak according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either

Comment: please attach your configuration files.

Answer (score 5):

On your JSP page use -

```
Username : ${sessionScope.user}
```