# PWC6236: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I was trying to learn Expression Languages and JSTL in java.
So while studying online,I found a code on web that demonstrated the use of expression languages and JSTL.
So I now have the basic hang of it. But when I tried to run the code on my pc,it's throwing some exception that I am unable to understand.

The two jsp codes are-

**1. index.jsp**

```
                            <html>
                           <head>
                              <title>EL Implicit Objects: Request Parameters</title>
                           </head>

                           <body>
                              <form action='paramm.jsp'>    
                         <table>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>First Name:</td>
                                       <td><input type='text' name='firstName'/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>Last Name:</td>
                                       <td><input type='text' name='lastName'/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          Select languages that you have worked with: 
                                       </td>
                                       <td>
                                          <select name='languages' size='7' 
                                              multiple='true'>
                                             <option value='Ada'>Ada</option>
                                             <option value='C'>C</option>
                                             <option value='C++'>C++</option>
                                             <option value='Cobol'>Cobol</option>
                                             <option value='Eiffel'>Eiffel</option>
                                             <option value='Objective-C'>
                                                Objective-C
                                             </option>
                                             <option value='Java'>Java</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                                 <p><input type='submit' value='Finish Survey'/>
                              </form>
                           </body>
                        </html>
```

and the second file,
**2. paramm.jsp**

```
                     <html>
                   <head>
                      <title>Accessing Request Parameters</title>   
                 </head>
                <body>
                      <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>

                      <font size='5'>
                         Skillset for:
                      </font>

                      <%-- Access the lastName and firstName request parameters
                           parameters by name --%>
               <c:out  value='${param.lastName}'/>
                      <c:out value='${param.firstName}'/>
                      <%-- Show all request parameters and their values --%>
                      <p><font size='5'>
                         All Request Parameters:
                      </font><p>

                      <%-- For every String[] item of paramValues... --%>
                      <c:forEach var='parameter' items='${paramValues}'> 
                         <ul>
                            <%-- Show the key, which is the request parameter
                                 name --%>
                            <li><b><c:out value='${parameter.key}'/></b>:</li>

                            <%-- Iterate over the values -- a String[] -- 
                                 associated with this request parameter --%>
                            <c:forEach var='value' items='${parameter.value}'>
                               <%-- Show the String value --%>
                               <c:out value='${value}'/>   
                            </c:forEach>
                         </ul>
                      </c:forEach>

                      <%-- Show values for the languages request parameter --%>
                      <font size='5'>
                         Languages:
                      </font><p>

                      <%-- paramValues.languages is a String [] of values for the 
                           languages request parameter --%>
                      <c:forEach var='language' items='${paramValues.languages}'> 
                         <c:out value='${language}'/>
                      </c:forEach>

                      <p>

                 <%-- Show the value of the param.languages map entry,
                           which is the first value for the languages
                           request parameter --%>
                      <c:out value="${'${'}param.languages} = ${param.languages}"/>
                   </body>
                </html>
```

*The error here is in the 21st line of paramm.jsp*

```
 <c:out  value='${param.lastName}'/>
 <c:out value='${param.firstName}'/>
```

exception-
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /paramm.jsp(21,26) PWC6236: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions**

Comment: This issue can come if tutorial you are referring is on old JSTL version and you are using new one. Change `<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>`

 to `<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>`

Comment: Just make sure you're reading a recent or an official tutorial and not a decade-old or an amateuristic one.

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes, I guess I need to refer better tutorials. The thing is most of them explained the implicit objects of EL and none of them demonstrated it with the help of an example. And that example-hunt kind of landed me on this code.

Comment: Could you suggest some good online tutorials?

P.S- Sorry for the absurd title. That was a mistake. :)

Comment: Start here for the explanation to your problem and for links to valuable resources in turn having valuable links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13455967

Comment: I am looking for a tutorial specifically. :)

Comment: It's there. Follow the precious links to get introduced and end up getting decent tutorial links.

Comment: Ohh,right! I am sorry again. Thank you! You are a life-saver,sir!