# Spring boot: How to convert thymeleaf to jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I recently followed a authentication and authorization tutorial using spring boot. It's working fine and I want to integrate it to my existing project. The tutorial I followed is written in thymeleaf and my current project is in jsp. I tried searching online but it's giving me errors.

This is my code:

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/","/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView test() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("welcomePage");
    model.addObject("title","Welcome");
    model.addObject("message","This is welcome page");
    return model;
}
```

Thymeleaf

```
<a th:if="${#request.userPrincipal != null}" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
```

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <a href="/">Home</a> | &nbsp; 
        <a href="/userInfo">User Info </a> | &nbsp; 
        <a href="/admin">Admin</a> | &nbsp; 

        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal != null}">
            <h2>Logout</h2> 
            <br>
        </c:if>


        ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal}



    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties

[image]

[image]

This is one of the problems that I am encountering. When I tried to run it, it's giving me this error.

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/_menu.jsp (line: [18], column: [2]) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [test] does not accept any expressions
```

This is my first time using this. Hope you could help me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please post your pom.xml file and your jsp page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428788/according-to-tld-or-attribute-directive-in-tag-file-attribute-items-does-not-ac)

Comment: @AvijitBarua done

Comment: @user7294900 I've already tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: You are getting error in `_menu` jsp page not in `welcomePage` !

Comment: check 18 no line in `_menu` jsp page

Comment: @trumanblack1025  What is in your `_menu` page ? Can you post this page ?

Comment: @trumanblack1025 solved your error ?

Comment: I think so. I'm still trying. I changed the uri to "http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"

Comment: @trumanblack1025 can you upload your project in github or anywhere else ?

Comment: sure! I'll upload it after I finished

Comment: @trumanblack1025 solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in you jsp instead of what you have:

" <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> "

Without the quotation marks